# Albums are split by artist

Tags: music-player

When I had 2.2 on my Desire, the album view of the stock music player would show each of the albums on the device.  Now I've upgraded to 2.3 (CM7), albums which have tracks by more than one artist appear multiple times in the list, once for each artist.  I'm using the same SD card with the same files -- what do I need to do (preferably to the app, not the files) to have them appear in a similar way to the way they looked under 2.2?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the easiest way to fix this is to add `albumartist` tags to each album.